# Do "nothing" while "condition"

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

While browsing the code for the Java 8 version of ForkJoinPool(which has a few interesting changes from Java 7) I ran across this construct ([here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java#l3207)):

```
do {} while (!blocker.isReleasable() &&
             !blocker.block());
```

I'm struggling with why you would write it like this instead of just

```
while (!blocker.isReleasable() &&
       !blocker.block());
```

Is it just a semantics/readability choice, since you could read the first construct as `do "nothing" while "conditions"`? Or is there some additional benefit I'm missing?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you read the comments at top of the file, just below the class declaration, there is a section which explains the use of this construct:

```
Style notes

===========

[...]

There are several occurrences of the unusual "do {} while
(!cas...)"  which is the simplest way to force an update of a
CAS'ed variable. There are also other coding oddities (including
several unnecessary-looking hoisted null checks) that help
some methods perform reasonably even when interpreted (not
compiled).
```

Comment: Since I needed a reminder myself: CAS is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap

Comment: You may have explained how the construct helps "to force an update of a CAS'ed variable".

Comment: But why is it causing an update of a CAS'ed variable unlike the `while` version?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the required knowledge to answer this question, but maybe the comment "simplest way to force an update" doesn't refer to the two versions (do-while vs. while), but rather to the way of updating a CAS'ed variable using an empty block in a while loop. That means that both (do-while **and** while) would update the CAS'ed variable. Read this question for reference: [In what situations can do-while be more efficient than while?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16437751/44522).

Comment: It doesn't say whether do {} while (condition) vs. while (condition) do ; makes any difference. If it makes a difference, then this is (a) an awful bad comment, (b) I consider it a _bug_ not having the comment at the statement itself, and (c) the fact that it makes a difference is a major WTF in the language.

Comment: @glglgl, this question is not about C, it's about Java too.

Comment: @xaizek Oups. Must have been half asleep :-O

Comment: This sounds like deep magic where the scope change `do {} while()` avoids a JIT optimization that the `while()` uses. The while statements are semantically equivalent so the difference must be in the implementation of the JVM.

Comment: The "Style Notes" don't say anything about why one version was chosen over the other. It only explains why a `while` loop was used **at all**. I think that the reasons are rather those in the [answer by Erik Vesteraas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24613352/3182664), namely 1. Clarity and **readability (!)**, and 2. Smaller bytecode (1 byte is 1 byte).

Answer (score 45):

`ForkJoinPool` makes extensive use of `compareAndSwap...` from `sun.misc.Unsafe` and most of the occurrences of `do {} while (...)` in `ForkJoinPool` can — as mentioned by other answers — be explained by this comment under the heading Style notes:

> ```
> * There are several occurrences of the unusual "do {} while
> * (!cas...)"  which is the simplest way to force an update of a
> * CAS'ed variable.
> ```

The choice to use write a `while`-loop with an empty body as `do {} while (condition)` seems however to be a mostly stylistic choice. This is perhaps clearer in `HashMap`, which happened to be updated in Java 8.

In the Java 7 `HashMap` you can find this:

```
while (index < t.length && (next = t[index++]) == null)
    ;
```

While much of the code around it has also changed, it is clear that the replacement in Java 8 is this:

```
do {} while (index < t.length && (next = t[index++]) == null);
```

The first version has the weakness that if the lone semicolon happened to be deleted it would change the meaning of the program depending on the following line.

As seen below, bytecode generated by `while (...) {}` and `do {} while (...);` is slightly different, but not in any way that should affect anything when run.

Java code:

```
class WhileTest {
    boolean condition;

    void waitWhile() {
        while(!condition);
    }

    void waitDoWhile() {
        do {} while(!condition);
    }
}
```

Generated code:

```
class WhileTest {
  boolean condition;

  WhileTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  void waitWhile();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: getfield      #2                  // Field condition:Z
       4: ifne          10
       7: goto          0
      10: return        

  void waitDoWhile();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: getfield      #2                  // Field condition:Z
       4: ifeq          0
       7: return        
}
```

Comment: Coming here from a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323549/weird-loops-used-in-spliterator-of-java-8) : This IMHO is a far better and more convincing answer than the currently accepted one.

Answer (score 8):

Leaving aside any potential performance benefits, there is a clear readability benefit.

With `while (X) ;` the trailing semicolon is not always obvious at first glance, you may be confused into thinking that the following statement or statements are inside the loop. For example:

```
while (x==process(y));
if (z=x) {
    // do stuff.
}
```

It would be very easy to misread the above as having the if statement inside the loop, and even if you did read it correctly it would be easy to think that it was a programming mistake and the if should be inside the loop.

With `do {} while(X);` though it is immediately at a glance clear that there is no body to the loop.

Comment: Why not simply write `while (x==process(y)) {}`? I think that would be almost as clear as the `do ... while()` solution.

Comment: @exilit that would help but because the `do {} while` construction has keywords inbetween the brackets it makes the separation cleaner. Even in that simple example we already have 4 brackets after each other `)){}` - you can easily see that that number could increase as the if grows more complicated...so it's easier to just not notice the `{}` in with all the others.

Answer (score 4):

If you will read comment above the code, It is mentioned that...

If the caller is not a `ForkJoinTask`, this method is behaviorally equivalent to

```
while (!blocker.isReleasable())
   if (blocker.block())
      return;
}
```

So it is just another form to implement above code in else part...!!

In [Style notes](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java#l520) it is mentioned that,

> There are several occurrences of the unusual "do {} while
>    (!cas...)"  which is the simplest way to force an update of a
>    CAS'ed variable.

And if you will see implementation of [ManagedLocker#isReleasable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker.html), It is updating the lock and returns `true` if blocking is unnecessary.

***Interpretation :***

Blank while loops are used to provide an interrupt until some condition reset to true/false.

Here, `do { } while(!...)` is a blocker/interrupt until `blocker.block()` will be `true` when `blocker.isReleasable()` is `false`. Loop will continue execution while `blocker` is not releasable (`!blocker.isReleasable()`) and `blocker` is not blocked !! Execution will be out of loop as soon as `blocker.block()` will set to true.

Note that, `do{ } while(...)` does not update CAS variable, but it guarantee that program will wait until variable gets updated (force to wait until variable gets updated).

Comment: Yes, but the do {} while (condition) construct is used in both cases. So the comment is indeed just a third way to write the same thing.

Comment: @ErikVesteraas updated the answer, It was in progress when you commented :D

Comment: So is the comment in the style notes implying that `while(!cas...)` would not force an update? That there is an actual technical difference as shown by the bytecode? I'm beginning to wonder if looking at isReleasable is a distraction, as there are many places where it is used for actual CAS-variables like this: `do {} while (!U.compareAndSwapLong(...));`

Comment: @ErikVesteraas I dont think `isReleasable()` is a distraction, See the interpretation edit.

Comment: Yes, I agree with what you have written, but it does not address whether `while(!cas...);` would be able to force an update on a CompareAndSwap-variable, or if `do {} while (!cas...);` is necessary, i.e. whether there is an actual technical difference or not.

Comment: @ErikVesteraas I think it can not force to update variable, but it can force program to wait until variable will be updated.

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar Can you please explain more clearly what the difference in the actual byte code is between the two constructs?  How does the `do{}` enable this interrupt?

Comment: @DavidWallace It is not like only `do{}while(...)` enables interrupt, it can be done with `while() { }` also. and for byte code, You can refer Erik's answer, in this pattern additional `goto` is not required because of `ifeq` instruction is there instead of `ifne`... I never said only `do{}` are used to enable interrupt !! ;) :D

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar - as Erik Vesteraas has shown the byte code in his answer, I cannot see any support for the "way to force an update of a CAS'ed variable" statement. There is virtually no difference between `while(...);` and `do{}while(...);` in the byte code. Only one unconditional jump less.

Comment: You forgot the word "simplest...", and for more you can read my answer again, I think it describes the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make something like this with:

```
if(true){
 //Do nothing ...
}
```