# Weird loops used in Spliterator of Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, spliterator

Does anyone know why the `java.util.Spliterator` implementation uses do-while rather than while loops, when the body of the loop is empty? For instance, the implementation of `forEachRemaining` is:

```
default void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    do { } while (tryAdvance(action));
}
```

Why would they use

```
do { } while (tryAdvance(action));
```

instead of

```
while(tryAdvance(action));
```

?

Are there any advantages I am not aware of?

Comment: so both loops run, as long as the termination condition `tryAdvance(action)` returns true.

Comment: While this is certainly a duplicate, I think that the accepted answer in the other question does not really answer the question (instead, it raises new ones...)

Comment: The choice was made purely on style.  The other two ways of writing it (`while (c());` and `while (c()) {}`), when reading the code, both seemed to raise questions along the lines of "is this really what the author meant?", whereas the form we settled on seemed to express the intent most clearly.  Your opinion may vary.

Comment: @BrianGoetz So, if it was a matter of style, then, it has nothing to do with the hidden synchronization which is implied in the answers of the other question?

Comment: Not in this case; the computation in this case is purely thread-local.

Answer (score -2):

The logic check executes after the body of the do{}.  This can be utilized many ways but does the same thing as a while loop with logic check at the end.  Because the do{} is empty the thread will wait until notified and then execute the logic check rather than execute the logic check then if true wait.

Comment: What thread are you talking about? Is there any (hidden) synchronization invloved?

Comment: "[...] Because the do{} is empty the thread will wait until notified [...]" This does not make sense. If some synchronization takes place, it can only be within the condition. Why should it matter whether the condition is at the start or the end of the loop?